# Jenkins_Execution of gradle script throws a permission denied error

Tags: jenkins

In jenkins iam facing an error when i trigger the gradle task.

When i execute the below shell 
cd /home/cucumberBdd
./gradlew cucumber

I got this error ".gradle/1.8/taskArtifacts/cache.properties.lock (Permission denied)"

Below are the configurations:
Os-Ubuntu
CI-Jenkins
Buildtool:Gradle
Script: gradle script

I have installed and mentioned the gradle version in the manage jenkins.
One thing which i noticed is in jenkins the above command + whoam i gives jenkins name but the project folder writes are with system user.Can anyone  tell me please how to avoid this error

Comment: Hi Is any one here to help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not put .gradle in the version control at all, only the gradle directory (without the dot) needs to be versioned. Everything in .gradle is just caching stuff and can be safely deleted and recreated.